# How to related the Chevalley basis with usual generators in su(N) algebra

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am reading the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0209056.pdf. I have a question about the SU(4) Chevalley basis.

It is well known that su(4) algebra can be written as
\begin{equation}
[R^i_{~j},R^k_{~l}]=\delta^k_j R^I_{~l}-\delta^i_l R^k_{~j}
\end{equation}
where $R^i_{~j}$ is the generator of su(4).

On the other hand we may write su(4) algebra in Chevalley basis with generator $(H_i, E^\pm_i), i=1,2,3$
\begin{equation}
[H_i,H_j]=0 ,~~ [ E_i{}^{ +}, E_j{}^{-} ] = \delta_{ij} H_j ~~
\quad [H_i ,  E_j{}^{\pm}] = \pm K_{ji}  E_j{}^{\pm}
\end{equation}
where $K_{ij}$ is cartan matrix for su(4) (eq.(3.25) in the paper).

Then one can relate $R_{ij}$ with Chevalley basis as follows
\begin{equation}
[ R^i{}_{j} ] =\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
\frac{1}{4}(3H_1{+2H_2}{+H_3})& E_1{}^{+} &
[E_1{}^{+},E_2{}^{+}]& [E_1{}^{+},[E_2{}^{+},E_3{}^{+}]]\\
E_1{}^{-} & \frac{1}{4}({-H_1}{+2H_2}{+H_3})& E_2{}^{+} &
[E_2{}^{+},E_3{}^{+}] \\
-[E_1{}^{-},E_2{}^{-}]& E_2{}^{-} &  -\frac{1}{4}(H_1{+2H_2}{-H_3}) &
E_3{}^{+} \\
[E_1{}^{-},[E_2{}^{-},E_3{}^{-}]] & -[E_2{}^{-},E_3{}^{-}]&
E_3{}^{-} & - \frac{1}{4}(H_1{+2H_2}{+3H_3}) \end{array}\right)
\end{equation}
which is (3.26) in the above paper. My question is that how to get the last equation, is there any general method?